# Validate copied|cloned input field for not have the same information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Lets said I have the following form information:

```
<form name="form_name" id="form_name" method="post">
    <div class="form_div_0">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_firstname[0]" id="input_firstname[0]" />
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_lastname[0]" id="input_lastname[0]" />
    </div>
    <button id="copy_form">Copy form</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The functionality of **Copy Form** button is to create a copy of the form inputs as for example if I click the button twice the form will change into this:

```
<form name="form_name" id="form_name" method="post">
    <div class="form_div_0">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_firstname[0]" id="input_firstname[0]" />
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_lastname[0]" id="input_lastname[0]" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_div_1">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_firstname[1]" id="input_firstname[1]" />
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_lastname[1]" id="input_lastname[1]" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_div_2">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_firstname[2]" id="input_firstname[2]" />
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_lastname[2]" id="input_lastname[2]" />
    </div>
    <button id="copy_form">Copy form</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

As you may notice I am copying only the inputs inside the `div class="form_div_0"`.

Having this information I need to find a way to validate the values entered on each input following this rule: firstname and lastname could not be equal at any time.

For example: if I enter firstname="John" lastname="Doe" on the inputs wrapped by `form_div_0` then I can not have in `form_div_1` or `form_div_2` or `form_div_n` the same values.

I should add that the inputs here is only and example of the form (it's a huge form with many input and different types like checkboxes, option, select and textarea)

Also as you can see I can create N copies (it will have a limit until 20) of the inputs.

Did you know a way to make this validation? Is there any workaround or libraries? Any advice?

The validation could be made as soon as input lost focus (meaning the user stop typing on it) or on submit but I prefer the first choice since otherwise the user might be typing in all the data and I want them to stop if any of this issues happen.

Comment: you can do it with jquery... ?!

Comment: @Alex Sure, jQuery is accepted here in fact I am tempted to use it, hopefully there is a library around and I am missing it ...

Comment: jquery is a library. you can use it for your needs. additionally, there is form validation, a plugin/ extension to use with jquery.

Comment: @Alex I know what jQuery is :) can you tell me the name of such library or are you saying that should be a library around for this but you didn't know it?

Comment: I already told you! "jquery form validation". Please note that StackOverflow is not the place to ask for plugins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do it as follows without any library just by using pure JS. I utilize ES6 tools but it's fairly simple to replace them by their ES5 equivalents if needed.

It does the duplicate checking on the fly once the field looses focus. There is no functionality assigned to the submit button as it will be used only to submit the form.

```js
function checkOnBlur(e){
  var enteredValues = inEls.map(inel => inel.value);
       enteredValue = e.currentTarget.value;
  if (enteredValues.filter(ev => ev === enteredValue).length > 1 && enteredValue !== ""){
    e.currentTarget.value = "";
    e.currentTarget.setAttribute("placeholder", "Duplicate..! Enter Again.");
    e.currentTarget.focus();
  } else e.currentTarget.removeAttribute("placeholder");
}

function cloneFormDiv(e){
  var dl = [...myForm.querySelectorAll("[class*='form_div']")],
  newDiv = dl[0].cloneNode(true),
newInEls = newDiv.querySelectorAll("input");

  e.preventDefault();
  newDiv.className = "form_div_" + dl.length;
  [newInEls[0].id, newInEls[0].name, newInEls[0].value] = ["input_firstname_" + dl.length, "input_firstname_" + dl.length,""];
  [newInEls[1].id, newInEls[1].name, newInEls[1].value] = ["input_lastname_" + dl.length, "input_lastname_" + dl.length,""];
  for(var inel of newInEls) {inel.addEventListener("blur", checkOnBlur);
                             inEls.push(inel)}
  myForm.appendChild(dl.concat(newDiv)
                       .reduce((frag,d) => (frag.appendChild(d),frag), document.createDocumentFragment()));
}

var myForm = document.getElementById("form_name"),
     inEls = [...myForm.querySelectorAll("div input")],
copyButton = myForm.querySelector("#copy_form");
for (var inel of inEls) inel.addEventListener("blur", checkOnBlur);
copyButton.addEventListener("click", cloneFormDiv);
```

```html
<form name="form_name" id="form_name">
  <div class="form_div_0">
    <label>Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="input_firstname_0" id="input_firstname_0" />
    <label>Lastname</label>
    <input type="text" name="input_lastname_0" id="input_lastname_0" />
  </div>
  <button id="copy_form">Copy form</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below solution, whether it works for you

```js
$(function(){
   $("#copy_form").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     var currentLength = $("[class^='form_div']").length;
      $(".error").html("");
      if (currentLength >  20 ) {
       $(".error").html("Reaches maximum form limit");
        return ;
      }
      var previousElement =  currentLength-1;
      
      var $formDiv = $(".form_div_"+ previousElement);
      var $firstNameLabel = $("<label/>").html("FirstName");
      var $lastNameLabel = $("<label/>").html("LastName");
      var $firstName = $("<input/>").attr("type","text").attr("name","input_firstname_"+currentLength).attr("id","input_firstname_"+currentLength);
      var $lastName = $("<input/>").attr("type","text").attr("name","input_lastname_"+currentLength).attr("id","input_lastname_"+currentLength);
    var $nextDiv = $("<div/>").attr("class","form_div_"+ currentLength).append($firstNameLabel).append($firstName).append($lastNameLabel).append($lastName);
    $formDiv.after($nextDiv);
    
   });
   
   $("#form_name").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var currentLength = $("[class^='form_div']").length;
      var firstNameArray  = [];
      var lastNameArray  = [];
      for( var i = 0; i < currentLength ; i++ ) {
          var $firstName = $("#input_firstname_"+i);
           var $lastName = $("#input_lastname_"+i);
           if ($firstName.val() != "" && $lastName.val() != "" && $firstName.val() === $lastName.val() ) {
               $(".error").html("First Name and Last Name are same in form" + i);
           }
           if (currentLength > 1 ) {
              if ($firstName.val() != "") {
              if ($.inArray($firstName.val(),firstNameArray ) == -1) {
              firstNameArray.push($firstName.val());
               }     
               else {      
                  $(".error").append("Duplicate firstName in form" + i);
               }
              } 
       
              if ($lastName.val() != "") {
               if ($.inArray($lastName.val(),lastNameArray ) == -1) {                                                                 lastNameArray.push($lastName.val());
               }
               else {      
                  $(".error").append("Duplicate lastName in form" + i);   
               }
             }
           }  
              
              
      }
      
      
   });
   
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form_name" id="form_name" method="post">

<span class="error"></span>
    <div class="form_div_0">
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_firstname[0]" id="input_firstname_0" />
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="input_lastname[0]" id="input_lastname_0" />
    </div>
    <button id="copy_form">Copy form</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```